# Correct parameters for JSON_QUERY?

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I'm using SQL in BigQuery. I have a table with a column of JSON-formatted data and I can't figure out how to use JSON_QUERY to extract the value for a key in it. I am not using JSON_VALUE because all the values for the specified_key key do not have double quotes around them.

All rows in the xyz column in table looks like this, which I know is JSON-formatted data:

```
{
first_key : "string",
specified_key : VALUE
}
```

This returns an error because the parameters specify two strings; I'm pretty sure my json_path parameter is correct but I cannot figure out what to put in place of xyz.

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY(xyz, '$.specified_key') AS key
FROM table
```

Comment: `xyz` column value just looks like a json but not json at all thus json functions will not work here!

Answer (score 0):

xyz column value just looks like a json but not json at all thus json functions will not work here!

if this would be real json as in below example  - it would worked

```
with your_table as (
select '''{
"first_key" : "string",
"specified_key" : "VALUE"
}''' xyz
)
select JSON_VALUE(xyz, '$.specified_key') AS key
from your_table
```

with output

[image]

In your specific case  - I suggest you to use below approach

```
select (
    select trim(arr[offset(1)])
    from unnest(split(trim(xyz, '{}'))) kv, 
    unnest([struct(split(kv, ':') as arr)])
    where trim(arr[offset(0)]) = 'specified_key' 
  ) as key
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question as

```
with your_table as (
select '''{
first_key : "string",
specified_key : VALUE
}''' xyz
)
```

output is

[image]